# How to add php echo within echo shortcode in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I'm trying to use an image for my title using the jQuery Collapse-O-Matic plugin, however I am using the do_shortcode echo and am stumbling a bit on how to add an echo within an echo. I've tried a few options including the Heredoc method but I am not sure how to implement with my particular code.

I've added my code below, can anyone point me in the right direction? All and any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[expand title="<img src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/schedule.png' />" trigpos="below"]this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..[/expand]'); ?>
```

Comment: that'll never work. `echo` performs output immediately. you probably do `do_shortcode('...' . get_template_director() . '...')` instead. No echo at all. just call the function and concatenate the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[expand title="<img src=\''. get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/schedule.png\' />" trigpos="below"]this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..this is content..[/expand]'); ?>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys! I had to remove the second single quote after the image but that did the trick! Is this just a form of "minimizing" php? I am no PHP expert so I really appreciate all the help, self teaching over here! :)

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use `echo` inside the `<img>` tag. The string returned by `get_template_directory_uri()` will be concatenated. Use this code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[expand title="<img src=\''.get_template_directory_uri().'/img/schedule.png\' />"
```

**Edit:** For more information refer to [Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) in the manual. In this case you can think about the function call like a variable. You could write the code this way:

```
$uri = get_template_directory_uri();
echo '<img src=\''.$uri.'/img/schedule.png\' />';
```

But instead of using a variable, you can call the function directly in the `echo` statement.

```
echo '<img src=\''.get_template_directory_uri().'/img/schedule.png\' />';
```

This statement can be divided into three parts:

- `'<img src=\''`: This is a string literal.
- `get_template_directory_uri()`: This is a function which returns a string.
- `'/img/schedule.png\' />'`: This is another string literal.

The dots (`.`) concatenate these three parts into a string which is then printed by `echo`. See [String Operations](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) for more details.

Comment: Awesome, huge help! Thank you for the lesson, learned a lot here!